# Using clock() as a timer in c

Tags: c

I have the following basic three lines of code to see if the `clock` is timing things correctly:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#define wait(seconds) sleep( seconds )

printf("%lu\n", clock());
wait(2);
printf("%lu\n", clock());
```

`wait()` seems to be working fine -- as when I run it, it 'feels' like it is pausing for 2s.

However, here is what the print command gives:

> 253778
>
> 253796

And so when I do something like:

```
(double) (clock() - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
```

It gives me useless results.

What is `clock()` doing here that I'm not understanding, and how can I fix this to get an accurate timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO C says that the *"`clock` function returns the implementation's best approximation to the processor time used by the program since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related only to the program invocation."*

In other words, it is not a real-time clock.

On platforms where C code runs as a process that can be put to sleep by an underlying operating system, a proper implementation of `clock` stops counting when that happens.

ISO C provides a function `time` that is intended to provide calendar time, encoded as a `time_t` arithmetic value. The `difftime` function computes the difference between two `time_t` values as a floating-point value of type `double` measuring seconds. On many systems, the precision of `time_t` is no better than one second, though.

There are POSIX functions for finer resolution time such as `gettimeofday`, or `clock_gettime` (with a suitable clock type argument).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a read of the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) for `clock()`, you will see the following listed in the notes:

> On several other implementations, the value returned by clock() also
>   includes the times of any children whose status has been collected via
>   wait(2) (or another wait-type call). Linux does not include the times
>   of waited-for children in the value returned by clock(). The times(2)
>   function, which explicitly returns (separate) information about the
>   caller and its children, may be preferable.

So `clock()` doesn't always include the time taken by something like `wait()` on all implementations. If you are on Linux, you may want to take a look at the `times()` function, defined in `sys/times.h`, as it returns a structure including the time (in clock ticks) taken by children (thus functions like `wait()` are included).

Comment: thanks. Could you please show the most basic implementation of using the `times()` function -- i.e., before and after the wait function?